# iOS Swift NSXMLPARSER does not parse the whole website

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, nsxmlparser

I've been stuck on a weird situation with NSXMLParser on Swift.

I've the following code to start parsing a full website from url

```
  func xmlAnalyser(tmp_http: String, tmp_url: String) {
    let tmp_str: String = tmp_http + tmp_url
    let url = NSURL(string: tmp_str)

    ParserXML = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: url!)!
    ParserXML.delegate = self
    ParserXML.parse()
}
```

For example, for the http://www.techcrunch.com the Parser does not parse the whole XML, some link tags are skipped somehow, and I can't figure it out, for example, with the following method

```
  func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {

    print("elementName: \(elementName)")

    if elementName == "link" {
        let type = attributeDict["type"]
        if type == "application/rss+xml" {
            print("feed found: \(href)")
        } else {
            print("not found")
        }
    }
}
```

somehow the parser can't find the type "application/rss+xml" but if I view the site source it's there. This does not happen to all websites, If I try with mashable.com for example the rss tag is found but on techcrunch it isn't.

Is it because the XML is too big? do I have to store it in two different variables and then parse them one by one?

Comment: I've found that NSXMLPARSER isn't the best way to Parse HTML. I'm searching for alternatives, but if you know a way to do it with NSXMLPARSER let me know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found that to Parse HTML the best way to do it is with Kanna Parser , previously known as SWIFT-HTML-Parser). 
Solved.

Answer (score 1):

Try [HTMLKit](https://github.com/iabudiab/HTMLKit). It can also be used with Swift. To solve your particular problem it would be something like this:

```
import HTMLKit
let document = HTMLDocument(string: htmlString) // htmlString is the source of the HTML page
let rssLinks = document.querySelectorAll("link[type='application/rss+xml']")
// you get an array of HTMLElements
for link in links {
  print(link.outerHTML)
  print(link["href"])
  // and so on ...
}
```

HTMLKit is a pure Objective-C HTML parser with CSS3 Selectors support. It is not a wrapper around libxml or any other library, but rather a complete WHATWG HTML specification-compliant implementation.